# How to generate ActiveQuery with client defined query string parameters safely in Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2, query-string, sql-injection

Is there a safe way to generate conditional clause for **Yii2 ORM** with **query string** parameters?
For example, we require a list of some food products, filtering by their properties:

```
GET /food/?weight[>]=1000&calories=[<]=200
```

And there is a plenty of different properties of the products: weight, calories, quantity, price.

I expect that it's possible to write something like (simplified code):

```
 $query = new \yii\db\Query();
 foreach ($_GET as $parameter => $condition){
    foreach ($condition as $operator => $value){
        $query->where(new SimpleCondition($parameter, $operator, $value));
    }
 }
```

But I **doubt** this approach is **safe**.

So, there are three questions:

1. How is it possible to define the properties from url safely? Can we sanitize the query string parameter *names* (not *values*) before using in `ActiveQuery::where` clause?
2. What's the way to properly define operators like `IN, AND, OR, >, <, >=, <=, etc.`?
3. Is there any native Yii2 component for filtering or should I use a third-party module?

Comment: This is definitely not safe - this code is vulnerable to SQL Injection.

Comment: @rob006 so, what's the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution.
It appears Yii2 provides such functionality with `DataFilter` class. 
The official [documentation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-data-datafilter) of the class and the [guide](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/output-data-providers#filtering-data-providers-using-data-filters) to use it

According to the documentation

1. Define a model for validation.

   ```
   class SearchModel extends \yii\base\Model
   {
       public $id;
       public $name;

       public function rules()
       {
           return [
               [['id', 'name'], 'trim'],
               ['id', 'integer'],
               ['name', 'string'],
           ];
       }
   }
   ```
2. Create the filter:

   ```
   $filter = new DataFilter(['searchModel' => $searchModel]);
   ```
3. Populate the filter  with data, validate

   ```
   if ($filter->load(\Yii::$app->request->get())) { 
      $filterCondition = $filter->build();
      if ($filterCondition === false) { // if error occure
          // the errors are stored in the filter instance
          return $filter;
      }
   }
   ```
4. Use the built condition in a `Query` filter

   ```
   $query->andWhere($filterCondition);
   ```